Is it possible to write task/function inside an interface?
Inside the interface, usually we declare clocking blocks and modports.  Is it possible to declare any task or function inside the interface?
If yes, tell me any example scenario.

Yes, it is possible to declare tasks and functions inside an interface.
Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2023, section
25.7 Tasks and functions in interfaces.  There are code examples in the Std.
Other examples:

Methods In Interfaces
Search Stack Overflow questions: task
Search Stack Overflow questions: function


You can put almost anything inside an interface that you can put inside a module except other module instances and primitives. An interface can be thought of a hardware driver for a standard protocol into a design.
In the UVM, there is a Dual Top architecture that splits drivers and monitor into time free class objects and synthesizable time consuming tasks and functions inside interfaces
